# Every Integral equals to zero?

Tags: integration, substitution

$$\int_a^b{f(x)}dx$$
let $u=k(x),$ where $ k(a)=0, k(b)=0 \\
k^{-1}(u)=x \\ (k^{-1})'(u) du =dx$

$$\int_{k(a)}^{k(b)} f(k^{-1}(u))\times (k^{-1})'(u)  du$$
$$=\int_{0}^{0} f(k^{-1}(u))\times (k^{-1})'(u) du$$
$$=0$$

If this is correct, then every integral would equal to zero, thus it has to be incorrect.

Comment: You'll have hard time finding an invertible map $k$ which has two inverse images for $0$.

Comment: Well, since $k(a)=k(b),$ $k$ can't be injective, and thus, $k^{-1}$ isn't actually well-defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Proof" all integrals are $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380669/proof-all-integrals-are-0)

Answer (score 3):

If $k(a) = 0 = k(b)$ then there is not exist $k^{-1}$

Well this $k$ is not inyective

Answer (score 2):

Let us play the game with
$$k(x):=(x-a)(b-x)$$ so that

$$dk=(a+b-2x)\,dx.$$

When $x$ moves from $a$ to $b$, $k$ increases from $0$ to $\dfrac{(b-a)^2}4$, then decreases back to $0$. At the same time, the sign of $dk$ changes from positive to negative.

Hence we will have a partial integral from $a$ to $\dfrac{a+b}2$ with a positive sign and another from $\dfrac{a+b}2$ to $0$ with a negative sign. Hence these two integrals do not cancel each other.